# Same files are needed to be committed every time I open project

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am currently working on a Xamarin.Forms application in a team of 3, using Visual Studio 2019. Despite my commit being the most recent, and me making no changes since the last commit, I still have two chances to commit. These are: \v16.suo and \DesignTimeBuild.dtbcache.v2 .

We are also having merge commit issues when one of the other 2 team members try to commit because there are files that have apparently been "changed" by each of us when in reality the only difference in the files are the local source of the project (C:\Users.....).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`[suo]`** The solution user options (.suo) file contains per-user solution options.
>   This file should not be checked in to source code control.
>
> **`[dtbcache]`** dtb stands for Design Time Build

- Those files are generated by Visual studio
- Add the extensions to your `.gitignore` and you will not see those changes again.
  Use this site to generate your `.gitignore` file: https://gitignore.io